# WPF DataGrid with RecognizesAccessKey turned off

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have a very basic WPF application with a MS SQL server as data source attached to it. My datagrid is declared as follows:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="456" Width="1018" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

When I run the app I see the data loaded into the grid from the database, but the column captions look odd. Every caption that originally contains an underscore has this underscore removed: `some_title` turns to `sometitle`.

I found out that's because the underscore is recognized as a control symbol to turn the next symbol into a mnemonic.

**How can I disable this behavior?**

I found out this behavior can be bypassed if you double the single underscores, i.e. `some__title` instead of `some_title`. But since my data source is an external database I can't influence that. Or maybe with a converter?

I figured the best approach would be to turn the property `RecognizesAccessKey` to `false`, but unfortunately it somehow isn't accessible.

I'm new to WPF, thanks for your help!

P.S. Her is a picture of Snoop (if that helps)
[image: DataGrid snooped]

**edit:** my target framework is .net 4.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution I could come up with is  intercepting the DataGrid event `AutoGeneratingColumn` and replace all underscores with two underscores like this:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn_1(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    string header = e.Column.Header.ToString();

    // Replace all underscores with two underscores, to prevent AccessKey handling
    e.Column.Header = header.Replace("_", "__");
}
```

In my understanding it is (sadly) not possible to override the value of `RecognizesAccessKey` of the underlying `ContentPresenter` without redefining the whole control template.
See this thread on the msdn forums: [How to set RecognizesAccessKey on labels without influencing other parameters?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2075fb80-6559-420d-88af-06c518d326b2/how-to-set-recognizesaccesskey-on-labels-without-influencing-other-parameters).

Answer (score 5):

Even though this is an old question, I came through solution. It might help someone.

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="456" Width="1018" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Border>
                            <ContentPresenter 
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                RecognizesAccessKey="False" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom columns , when you use custom column then you can define columns caption as you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this approach would require to manually define all columns plus its bindings. However, I could write a function that automatically generates these columns.  I'm looking for a more generic and declarative approach. Maybe with with `style` and `setter`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the accepted answer, if you want to keep the original style of datagrid do as seen below and change the ContentPresenter's RecognizeAccessKey to False.

[image]

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Themes:DataGridHeaderBorder BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" IsClickable="{TemplateBinding CanUserSort}" IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SortDirection="{TemplateBinding SortDirection}" SeparatorBrush="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}" SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}">
                            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="False" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Themes:DataGridHeaderBorder>
                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Thumb.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="8"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Thumb.Style>
                        </Thumb>
                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <Thumb.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="8"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Thumb.Style>
                        </Thumb>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```